# How to create a function that return the highest id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot make work this function, i got a lot mistakes from it. i have researched about the syntaxis when it comes to declare variables and functions.
But i still cannot do it.

this is the code i have tried so far, but none of them work.

```
Create function Consecutive()
returns int
return (select @id := max(id) from pais);
```

or

```
Create function Consecutive()
returns int
BEGIN
DECLARE id int;
set id = (select max(id) from pais;
return id;
END
```

Comment: Don't do this. Nothing good can come of it.

Comment: @strawberry is for a homework

Comment: @Manguerav Strawberry is correctly pointing out that this method is frequently mis-used to decide what the *next* ID will be, when an `auto_increment` column is a much safer approach due to what's known as a "race condition".

Comment: Well, if it's *your* homework, how come *we're* doing it?

Comment: I see no evidence that you are setting delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION consecutive()
RETURNS integer
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT max(id)
                 FROM pais);
END;
```

this is the solution to my question.

Comment: i would not call that a solution, if i was you i would research what [race condition(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) are

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for a variable. You can directly return the scalar subquery.

```
CREATE FUNCTION consecutive()
                RETURNS integer
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT max(id)
                 FROM pais);
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f8b0a20c9f6b4351253350dc475e9a8d)

Comment: This one looks cleaner, i just dont know why im getting mistakes after the end, It says "END" is not valid at this position, expecting.....