# How to create a function that return the number of rows of a table?

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i have a homework about doing a function in MySQL.

This is the solution in SQL SERVER, but how do i do it in MySQL?

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumberOfRows()
RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @numberOfRows int
        set @numberOfRows = (Select COUNT(id) From Producto)
        return @numberOfRows
    END

    print dbo.NumberOfRows()
```

Comment: See: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/

Comment: Pretty close to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454026/how-to-create-a-function-that-return-the-highest-id (just a different aggregation function and table name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumberOfRows()
RETURNS integer
deterministic
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT count(idpais)
                 FROM pais);
END;
```